# How to transform JS nested object keys to hierarchical array schema

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to transform a nested *object* comprised of only keys into a nested *array* of data comprised of the data referenced by those keys, so that it conforms to a d3.js schema for a bubblechart.

The nested object looks like this:

```
{
   "f5eade20-110f-11e5-9c61-33ffcb46c0ef":{

   },
   "ff4477e0-6a2c-11e4-afd1-83393415d9ef":{
      "0153f8b0-265a-11e4-8585-9b3341099b01":{
         "0159c510-265a-11e4-8585-9b3341099b01":{
            "11615f20-fbf9-11e4-b3d5-771ea6705f5b":{

            }
         },
         "83180020-f504-11e4-917c-b121cbe20dd2":{

         },
         "ddc13830-fa76-11e4-a09d-430b71e0fc3f":{

         }
      },
      "022bbb10-265a-11e4-8585-9b3341099b01":{
         "7daa5900-fbf6-11e4-bdf8-fdcd51308cde":{

         },
         "cbbad030-6c0d-11e4-b161-d9c9c481a5bc":{
            "3990b5c0-f53e-11e4-917c-b121cbe20dd2":{

            }
         },
         "7347bc80-38fd-11e4-a2b7-d7a74243b515":{
            "98b00f90-fb53-11e4-bd16-359096879648":{

            }
         },
         "a7dd2b50-36ce-11e4-b2d6-85c2a0c3f504":{
            "7347bc80-38fd-11e4-a2b7-d7a74243b515":{
               "f823a7b0-f753-11e4-b9ef-1bae8d43be66":{

               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

After looking up these keys in another array to get their value (`name` attribute), the transform needs to look like this for d3.js to read it:

```
{
   "name":"Parent 1",
   "children":[
      {
         "name":"Child 1",
         "children":[
            {
               "name":"Child 1",
               "children":null
            },
            {
               "name":"Grandchild 1.1",
               "children":null
            },
            {
               "name":"Grandchild 1.2",
               "children":null
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"Child 2",
         "children":[
            {
               "name":"Child 2",
               "children":null
            },
            {
               "name":"Grandchild 2.1",
               "children":null
            },
            {
               "name":"Grandchild 2.2",
               "children":null
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"Child 3",
         "children":[
            {
               "name":"Child 3",
               "children":null
            },
            {
               "name":"Grandchild 3.1",
               "children":null
            },
            {
               "name":"Grandchild 3.2",
               "children":null
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"Child 4",
         "children":[
            {
               "name":"Child 4",
               "children":null
            },
            {
               "name":"Grandchild 4.1",
               "children":null
            },
            {
               "name":"Grandchild 4.2",
               "children":null
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I've beat my head against a wall trying to figure out how to do this and would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a recursive function for this. Below is some basic stuff to get you started.

```js
var obj = {
   "f5eade20-110f-11e5-9c61-33ffcb46c0ef":{

   },
   "ff4477e0-6a2c-11e4-afd1-83393415d9ef":{
      "0153f8b0-265a-11e4-8585-9b3341099b01":{
         "0159c510-265a-11e4-8585-9b3341099b01":{
            "11615f20-fbf9-11e4-b3d5-771ea6705f5b":{

            }
         },
         "83180020-f504-11e4-917c-b121cbe20dd2":{

         },
         "ddc13830-fa76-11e4-a09d-430b71e0fc3f":{

         }
      },
      "022bbb10-265a-11e4-8585-9b3341099b01":{
         "7daa5900-fbf6-11e4-bdf8-fdcd51308cde":{

         },
         "cbbad030-6c0d-11e4-b161-d9c9c481a5bc":{
            "3990b5c0-f53e-11e4-917c-b121cbe20dd2":{

            }
         },
         "7347bc80-38fd-11e4-a2b7-d7a74243b515":{
            "98b00f90-fb53-11e4-bd16-359096879648":{

            }
         },
         "a7dd2b50-36ce-11e4-b2d6-85c2a0c3f504":{
            "7347bc80-38fd-11e4-a2b7-d7a74243b515":{
               "f823a7b0-f753-11e4-b9ef-1bae8d43be66":{

               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
};

var final_obj = Convert(obj);

function Convert(obj_to_convert) {
  var new_obj = [];
  for (var i in obj_to_convert) {
    new_obj.push({
      name: i,
      children: Convert(obj_to_convert[i])
    });
  }
  return new_obj;
};

$('#results').text(JSON.stringify(final_obj, null, 4));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<pre id="results"></pre>
```